# Convert date in Javascript (luxon)

Tags: javascript

I am using luxon to convert the date:

```js
console.log(DateTime.now('Sun Jan 23 2003 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)').toISODate())
```

Now i get: `2022-04-07`. But this is today's day, but i need to get this format from this: `Sun Jan 23 2003 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)`.
 How to get this using `luxon` library?

Comment: Can be done in plain JavaScript:  new Date(Date.parse('Sun Jan 23 2003 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)')).toISOString();

Answer (score 0):

Try using console.log(DateTime.local('Sun Jan 23 2003 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)').toISODate()).
By using DateTime.now(etc...), it automatically returns the current date.

Comment: When i use console.log(DateTime.local('Sun Jan 23 2003 00:00:00 GMT+0200 (Eastern European Standard Time)').toISODate()) , i get null, why?

Comment: I believe that you may be using the wrong format, Luxon's format, when using .local, should be year, month, day, hour, minute, second, millisecond. I think this might be the reason you are getting null.